# How to show "only" defined functions in GNU cflow?

Tags: c, cflow

I have a `C` file like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
#include <linux/ieee80211.h>
#include <linux/export.h>
#include <net/cfg80211.h>
#include "nl80211.h"
#include "core.h"
#include "rdev-ops.h"

int __cfg80211_stop_ap(struct cfg80211_registered_device *rdev,
               struct net_device *dev, bool notify)
{
    struct wireless_dev *wdev = dev->ieee80211_ptr;
    int err;

    ASSERT_WDEV_LOCK(wdev);

    if (!rdev->ops->stop_ap)
        return -EOPNOTSUPP;

    if (dev->ieee80211_ptr->iftype != NL80211_IFTYPE_AP &&
        dev->ieee80211_ptr->iftype != NL80211_IFTYPE_P2P_GO)
        return -EOPNOTSUPP;

    if (!wdev->beacon_interval)
        return -ENOENT;

    err = rdev_stop_ap(rdev, dev);
    if (!err) {
        wdev->conn_owner_nlportid = 0;
        wdev->beacon_interval = 0;
        memset(&wdev->chandef, 0, sizeof(wdev->chandef));
        wdev->ssid_len = 0;
        rdev_set_qos_map(rdev, dev, NULL);
        if (notify)
            nl80211_send_ap_stopped(wdev);

        /* Should we apply the grace period during beaconing interface
         * shutdown also?
         */
        cfg80211_sched_dfs_chan_update(rdev);
    }

    schedule_work(&cfg80211_disconnect_work);

    return err;
}

int cfg80211_stop_ap(struct cfg80211_registered_device *rdev,
             struct net_device *dev, bool notify)
{
    struct wireless_dev *wdev = dev->ieee80211_ptr;
    int err;

    wdev_lock(wdev);
    err = __cfg80211_stop_ap(rdev, dev, notify);
    wdev_unlock(wdev);

    return err;
}
```

After executing command [cflow](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/): `cflow ap.c -i_ -d2 --omit-arguments --omit-symbol-name`, I get output:

```
__cfg80211_stop_ap() <int () at ap.c:9>:
    ASSERT_WDEV_LOCK()
    rdev_stop_ap()
    memset()
    rdev_set_qos_map()
    nl80211_send_ap_stopped()
    cfg80211_sched_dfs_chan_update()
    schedule_work()
cfg80211_stop_ap() <int () at ap.c:48>:
    wdev_lock()
    __cfg80211_stop_ap() <int () at ap.c:9>:
    wdev_unlock()
```

What I want is that functions not found in the file shouldn't be shown.
I want my output like:

```
__cfg80211_stop_ap() <int () at ap.c:9>:
cfg80211_stop_ap() <int () at ap.c:48>:
    __cfg80211_stop_ap() <int () at ap.c:9>:
```

Comment: I did not see any facility to ignore C library functions

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it to a perl filter like this:

```
cflow ap.c | perl -e 'while(<>){if(/at ap.c/){print;}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Valter's answer, here's a version with `sed` for filtering:

```
cflow --brief --omit-arguments --omit-symbol-names --no-main stream_buffer.c 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/stream_buffer.c/p'
```

The `2>/dev/null` part is to suppress errors with missing definitions (expected when some functions are defined in other files).

You can wrap this up in a convenience script so you don't have to duplicate typing the file names:

```
cat cflowfile.sh                          
cflow --brief --omit-arguments --omit-symbol-names --no-main $1 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/'$1'/p' | sed -n 's/ <.*//p'
```

Here's an example of running it on FreeRTOS's [`stream_buffer.c`](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/stream_buffer.c):

```
./cflowfile.sh stream_buffer.c

ucStreamBufferGetStreamBufferType()
uxStreamBufferGetStreamBufferNumber()
vStreamBufferDelete()
vStreamBufferSetStreamBufferNumber()
xStreamBufferBytesAvailable()
    prvBytesInBuffer()
xStreamBufferGenericCreateStatic()
    prvInitialiseNewStreamBuffer()
xStreamBufferIsEmpty()
xStreamBufferIsFull()
    xStreamBufferSpacesAvailable()
xStreamBufferNextMessageLengthBytes()
    prvBytesInBuffer()
    prvReadBytesFromBuffer()
xStreamBufferReceive()
    prvBytesInBuffer()
    prvReadMessageFromBuffer()
        prvReadBytesFromBuffer()
xStreamBufferReceiveCompletedFromISR()
xStreamBufferReceiveFromISR()
    prvBytesInBuffer()
    prvReadMessageFromBuffer()
xStreamBufferReset()
    prvInitialiseNewStreamBuffer()
xStreamBufferSend()
    xStreamBufferSpacesAvailable()
    prvWriteMessageToBuffer()
        prvWriteBytesToBuffer()
    prvBytesInBuffer()
xStreamBufferSendCompletedFromISR()
xStreamBufferSendFromISR()
    xStreamBufferSpacesAvailable()
    prvWriteMessageToBuffer()
    prvBytesInBuffer()
xStreamBufferSetTriggerLevel()
```

I unfortunately haven't arrived at a great way to do this with `cflow`s `--reverse` option. That might require a custom post-processing script to invert the above output, rather than simply using the `--reverse` flag in cflow. Ideally, we'd be able to generate output like the following:

```
./todo-cflowfile-reverse.sh stream_buffer.c

prvBytesInBuffer()
  xStreamBufferBytesAvailable()
  xStreamBufferNextMessageLengthBytes()
  xStreamBufferReceive()
  xStreamBufferReceiveFromISR()
  xStreamBufferSend()
  xStreamBufferSendFromISR()
prvReadBytesFromBuffer()
  prvReadMessageFromBuffer()
    xStreamBufferReceive()
    xStreamBufferReceiveFromISR()
  xStreamBufferNextMessageLengthBytes()
prvInitialiseNewStreamBuffer()
  xStreamBufferGenericCreateStatic()
  xStreamBufferReset()
prvWriteBytesToBuffer()
  prvWriteMessageToBuffer()
    xStreamBufferSend()
    xStreamBufferSendFromISR()
xStreamBufferSpacesAvailable()
  xStreamBufferIsFull()
  xStreamBufferSend()
  xStreamBufferSendFromISR()
```